# Something is going wrong with this onclick

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateAlphaNumeric()
{
alert("function start");
var alphabets="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var numbers="0123456789";
var flag=true;
var prod_id=document.getElementByID("productid").value;
alert(prod_id);
for(var i=0;i<prod_id.length;i++)
{
if(alphabets.indexOf(prod_id.charAt(i))==-1 || numbers.indexOf(prod_id.charAt(i)==-1)
{
alert("value must be alphanumeric");
break;
}
}


var prod_type=document.myform.producttype.value;
for(var i=0;i<prod_type.length;i++)
{
if(alphabets.indexOf(prod_type.charAt(i))==-1 || numbers.indexOf(prod_type.charAt(i)==-1)
{
alert("value must be alphanumeric");
break;
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myform" action="http://localhost:8080/examples/Submit.HTML" method="POST">

<br><br>
Prodcut ID:<input type="text" name="productid" id="productid" size="25" ">
<br><br>
Product Type:<input type="text" name="producttype" id="producttype" size="25" ">
<br><br>
</div>

<input type="submit"  onclick="validateAlphaNumeric()" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a test page being written to only learn basics.When I am pressing Submit there is no checking happening and it goes to Submit.html page.why? What modification is needed here?

```
<input type="submit"  onclick="validateAlphaNumeric()" value="Submit">
```

What exactly happens when I am pressing this button?

```
var prod_id=document.getElementByID("productid").value;

  var prod_type=document.myform.producttype.value;
```

both mechanisms  are same ?

```
This is the Modified one.But still not working. Please help

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateAlphaNumeric()
{

var alphabets="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var numbers="0123456789";
var flag=true;
var prod_id=document.getElementByID("productid").value;

for(var i=0;i<prod_id.length;i++)
{
if(alphabets.indexOf(prod_id.charAt(i))==-1 && numbers.indexOf(prod_id.charAt(i)==-1))
{
alert("value must be alphanumeric");
return false;
}
}


var prod_type=document.myform.producttype.value;
for(var i=0;i<prod_type.length;i++)
{
if(alphabets.indexOf(prod_type.charAt(i))==-1 && numbers.indexOf(prod_type.charAt(i)==-1))
{
alert("value must be alphanumeric");
return false;
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myform" action="http://localhost:8080/examples/Submit.HTML" method="POST">

<br><br>
Prodcut ID:<input type="text" name="productid" id="productid" size="25" ">
<br><br>
Product Type:<input type="text" name="producttype" id="producttype" size="25" ">
<br><br>
</div>

<input type="submit"  onclick="validateAlphaNumeric(); " value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try returning false when you shouldn't continue.

Comment: It's better to put the handler on the form itself rather than the button otherwise you're messing with usability.

Comment: What compels you to post code without any indentation?

Answer (score 1):

there you go you forgot closing parenthesis for if statements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateAlphaNumeric()
{
alert("function start");
var alphabets="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var numbers="0123456789";
var flag=true;
var prod_id=document.getElementByID("productid").value;
alert(prod_id);
for(var i=0;i<prod_id.length;i++)
{
if(alphabets.indexOf(prod_id.charAt(i))==-1 && numbers.indexOf(prod_id.charAt(i)==-1))
{
alert("value must be alphanumeric");
break;
}
}


var prod_type=document.myform.producttype.value;
for(var i=0;i<prod_type.length;i++)
{
if(alphabets.indexOf(prod_type.charAt(i))==-1 && numbers.indexOf(prod_type.charAt(i)==-1))
{
alert("value must be alphanumeric");
break;
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">

<br><br>
Prodcut ID:<input type="text" name="productid" id="productid" size="25" ">
<br><br>
Product Type:<input type="text" name="producttype" id="producttype" size="25" ">
<br><br>
</div>

<input type="submit"  onclick="validateAlphaNumeric()" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see the modified version and help

Answer (score 0):

if You want didn't go to Action page You must put **return false;** at end of **onclick** like this

```
onclick="validateAlphaNumeric();return false;"
```

or put **return false;** at end of function that you Call with **return false;** you say browser don't submit

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false when validation fails